# CRM 2011- LINQ query joining Account, Case and Activity entity

Tags: linq, join, dynamics-crm-2011

I try to make the following query using Account, Case and Activity entities :

```
*var findCases = 
from a in context.AccountSet 
join c in context.IncidentSet
on a.AccountId equals c.CustomerId.Id 
join p in context.ActivityPointerSet 
on c.Id equals p.RegardingObjectId.Id 
select new 
{
TicketNumber = c.TicketNumber,
IncidentId = c.IncidentId,
CreatedOn = c.CreatedOn,
StateCode = c.StateCode,
AccountName = a.Name
};*
```

The execution of this query gives the error:

*AttributeFrom and AttributeTo must be either both specified or both ommited. You can not pass only one or the other. AttributeFrom: , AttributeTo: regardingobjectid*

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Regards.
Radu Antonache

Comment: you have `,` after `a.Name`

Comment: Yes, indeed but there is a typo in my post not in my project. I have corrected my post, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `CasesForAccount` from the query..

```
*var findCases = 
    from a in context.AccountSet 
    join c in context.IncidentSet
    on a.AccountId equals c.CustomerId.Id 
    join p in context.ActivityPointerSet 
    on c.Id equals p.RegardingObjectId.Id 
    select new
    {
    TicketNumber = c.TicketNumber,
    IncidentId = c.IncidentId,
    CreatedOn = c.CreatedOn,
    StateCode = c.StateCode,
    AccountName = a.Name
    };*
```

Comment: I have removed CasesForAccount from the query but I have the same error.

Comment: What is c.ID? Shouldn't it be c.IncidentID? Also, why are you joining to Activity if your result set doesn't include any activity fields?

Comment: You are right, I have replaced c.Id with c.IncidentId and the query is ok. I join Activity because I will need some fields from it. Thank you very much.